# Thread running a heavy method is slowing down the UI in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

Does anyone know why this code is slowing down the UI:

```
Thread trdGenerateTrajectory = new Thread(() => HeavyMethod());
trdGenerateTrajectory.Start();
trdGenerateTrajectory.Join();
```

This is supposed to be in a separate thread than the main thread, am I right? If so, why running it slows down/freezes the UL?

EDIT: Thanks for your comments. I removed Join(), but it still freezes the UI. Any idea?

UPDATE: The HeavyMethod() method is calling a method from a Matlab dll that I created. The method in the dll generates manipulation trajectory for a robot. My project is a heavy robotics project that communicates with lots of hardware/devices. The project has 12 backgroundworkers and one timer. The timer is responsible for updating the UI and all of the texts/colors/images/... on it. I haven't had any issue so far with the backgroundworkers and the timer and no matter how heavy were the tasks they are runing, I never saw any delay or stop on the timer and UI update. However, when I call this specific method in Matlab dll, I see a full stop on UI being updated until the method is completed. This is what I experienced:

1. I used threads (above code) with no luck.
2. I then moved the method and the process after running method into another backgroundworker, again with no luck.

Then I realized that just some of the textboxes on my form are experiencing this issue. They are those that are getting their values from another method of the same Matlab dll. That was the time that I realized that this issue has nothing to do with threads/backgroundworkers and is related to the Matlab way of running methods. Maybe it is single threaded!? Anyway, I though it may help if I make separate dll for this specific method that generates trajectory, so I created another dll, but I experienced the exact same issue. It seems like Matlab dll can only run one method at a time no matter if you call them from different threads or even from separate dll. I believe I should ask this in separate SO question and I will, but, in the meantime, do you have any comment on this? (**Update:** I didn't receive any reply so I posted a new question: [Calling two functions from a single Matlab dll at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27649939/3179989))

Comment: Are you using cpusets - and is the code on a multicore system?

Comment: Async vs sync,  dispatcher thread and many more can help you.  You created a thread what about how and when to run it.  And what happens in the UI thread while it is running?  Is there a progress bar running?

Comment: What kind of program is this? Windows forms?

Comment: Yes, it is on a 8-core system. I have a timer that updating texboxes. When I run the above code, the texts in the textboxes stop updating until this thread is finished. My program is Winform.

Comment: If your UI is still blocking after removing Join() then the code in HeavyMethod() is improperly using the main UI thread.  Perhaps you've got an Invoke() call in there?...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you're running your computation on a background thread, your `Join` call causes your UI thread to block anyway until your computation completes.

The proper way to do this today would be using the `async` and `await` keywords. If you really want to restrict yourself to threads, you can use an [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call within the thread to dispatch control back to the UI thread once the computation completes:

```
Thread trdGenerateTrajectory = new Thread(() => 
{
    HeavyMethod();

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         // Update UI here.
    }));
});

trdGenerateTrajectory.Start();
// trdGenerateTrajectory.Join(); <- do not block
```

**Edit**: Assuming that you want to run your computation in response to some button click (or any other event), you can use the async pattern in the event handler like so:

```
private async void myButton_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(HeavyMethod);

    // Update UI here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please show me how to use async and await to solve this?

Comment: Thank you. I tried my simple code without Join(). It is still freezing the UI. Do you have any idea on what would be the reason?

Comment: By "freezing" the UI, do you mean that you don't get any progress updates, or that your UI stops responding to user input altogether? If it's the latter, then like Idle_Mind said, your `HeavyMethod` might be internally dispatching some calls to the UI thread. This could even be happening from a library you call; for example, the Office Object Model transparently runs all calls on the UI thread. Could you give us some more context within your question on what `HeavyMethod` does?

Comment: Another possibility: Your `HeavyMethod` might be spawning more parallel processing (via child threads or tasks) that shoots your CPU usage up to 100%. Thus, although the UI thread is free, the OS struggles to allocate it a core to run on. Again, these are just speculations; it would be best if you could show us a simple example of what's happening in `HeavyMethod`.

Comment: many thanks for your comments. I updated my main question and explained in detail, I beleive.

Answer (score 4):

You're starting the thread and immediately joining it. Joining the thread means that you are waiting for it to end.

Normally, user interfaces are single threaded. This means that your method needs to return for another event to be processed.

Comment: The HeavyMethod() is generating some data. This means that I need to process the data right after the thread is finished. I am trying to have something similar to DoWork() method of backgroundworkers but just using Threads. Is it possible? I beleive if I move the HeavyMethod() method to a backgroundworker, it wont slow down the UI, am I right?

Comment: You could always do your processing in the lambda after the `HeavyMethod()` call and remove the call to `Join()`.